# After printing TChart I can't draw lines

Tags: lazarus, freepascal, teechart

I have simple chart (TChart) on a form. I tried printing this chart with:

```
Chart1.Draw(TPrinterDrawer.Create(Printer), myRect);
```

and chart is printed OK. But when I try to draw line(s) after drawing the chart, ie.:

```
printer.Canvas.MoveTo(Printer.PageWidth div 6, (Printer.PageHeight *4) div 5);  
printer.Canvas.LineTo(Printer.PageWidth div 2, (Printer.PageHeight *4) div 5);
```

No lines are drawn (on real printer or bitmap canvas) from printed chart to end of doc.

When I choose Microsoft XPS Document writer, lines are printed on the page.
What do I need to do to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in TAChart because the pen is in pmXor mode after printing the chart. Should be fixed in Lazarus trunk (will be back-ported to version 1.6.2)

Comment: Thanks @wp_1233996 for answer. Is any way to get around this problem?

Comment: Use the trunk version, or wait for version 1.6.2. If don't want to use trunk or wait for the new version you could also edit the TAChartSources:

Comment: Sorry I hit the return key too early... This is what you have to change: Open the file TAGraph.pas, it's in the folder components/tachart of your Lazarus installation. Find the implementation of the method TChart.Draw(...). Before the "end;" of this procedure add these two lines: "ADrawer.SetXor(false); ADrawer.PrepareSimplePen(clBlack);" (I can't enter a linebreak here, but I guess you understand what I mean). Then recompile the package tachartlazaruspkg.lpk. (Don't forget to make a backup copy of TAGraph.pas!)

Comment: I used solution with correction TAGraph.pas. Works great! Thank you very much @wp_1233996.